# is it possible to search for a result WITHIN a set of results when using sphinxsearch?

Tags: sphinx

when using sphinxsearch, is it possible to search for a result within a set of results?

to simplify, imagine the following scenario:

searching for "computer", returns 3 results:

```
apple computer
ibm computer
evil computer
```

then within those results doing another search for "evil", which would return

```
evil computer
```

to those that would recommend consolidating the queries into a single one, we would like to run a MATCH ANY based query on the first result, and a MATCH ALL on the 2nd based query. so consolidating the queries wouldnt work.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wanted to chime in regarding this question.

this is possible using sphinxes extended matching mode.

a good writeup on how to do this is available in:

http://mmakaay.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/extended-query-building-for-the-sphinx-search-engine/

enjoy.